# Set the width of the homepage, such that viewing in any mode doesnt impact the page layout

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, design

Environment: SharePoint 2013

My homepage appears fine if viewed in 1920* 1080 pixels.
However on reducing the pixel view testing via IE Developer Tool and reducing the view to 70% or 80%.
Web part Alignment doesn't appears properly,( Web part doesn't show on the same row with other content)

How can i Fix web part so even if the view is changed to lower pixel size / view size it doesn't impact the way Web parts are aligned on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options,

1. Create a pagelayout with definite height and with and create webpart zones with required width and height. Create your home page using the new page layout and add webparts to it. You may also set height and width for the webparts as well.
2. If you are not interested to create a page layout, insert a table in the page content area with fixed width and height and add webparts into the respective cells.

Comment: creating a new page layout will be difficult as we have everything placed on the home page with the required CSS changes. So what we are after is just to set page width and height. Any way to do that ?

Comment: You may set height and with using CSS itself. Whats tricky in it?

Comment: well can set the width by following article: http://www.n8d.at/blog/fixed-width-design-in-sharepoint-2013-the-fast-way/

But not sure if that would zoom out the content when viewed in lower screen resolution (below 1920* 1080)

Comment: Use CSS property overflow, set it to scroll (overflow:scroll;). If you set a fixed width and height, if the resolution is less there wont be changes in allignment but you will get scrollbars for lower resolution. Check it out.

Comment: Using Stylebot in Google Chrome, I tried setting the Width of the page to: 1560px and height: 850px.
Also added overflow: scroll
CSS code - 

div.col-lg-10.col-md-9.col-sm-12 {
    width: 1560px;
    height: 850px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

Still the web part alignment getting impacted,

Example screenshot for better understanding - 
a) Home Pg appears in Full screen with width set to 1560px, 

http://imgur.com/gcoTsxY

b) When, Home Pg appears in Full screen with width set to 1560px, but browser Is set to restore down mode .

http://imgur.com/3F9vVHz

Comment: reviving our discussion any other suggestion to get the page content alignment not impacted if viewed in low resolution screen.

Adding Table to a Webpart Zone and testing, will that work even if viewed in Lower Resolution Screen?

Comment: I tried adding a table on the page, by placing a content editor and inserting table. But later cant add webpart to the table. Please suggest how to add the webpart within a table.